# 10 Lamps setup 220v ac, would it be safe?

Tags: safety, parallel, lamp

I am not an electrical engineering or anything, I am just a curious person trying things at my home for fun.

I want to setup a lamp system for my sister's mirror where I would need to use 10 lamps from just one socket.

I made a diagram of what I mean, all 10 lamps in parallel with an interrupter in between the plug.
[image]

**My biggest question is, would it be safe to do this connection?** Is there a better way of doing it? I am scared of it not being safe since it's a lot of things on just one 220v ac plug.

Each lamp is 3W A5 using the socket E24.
[image]

Comment: A 220v, 5 watt lamp will use 23 milliamps and it's resistance will be 9,680 ohms. There is something wrong with your numbers. The lamps cannot be 5 watts and use 3 amps in your circuit. Maybe you meant 0.3 amps?

Comment: I suggest you study Ohm's Laws before continuing.

1) Power = Voltage x Current

2) Voltage = Current x Resistance

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake, on the lamp it says A5 3W, here is an image of it: https://i.imgur.com/4NnJSaL.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your lamp draws 30mA, that is bugger all. Ten times that is 300mA, still bugger all. Even the smallest sizes of mains wiring will easilly carry that.

Your main concerns here are making sure everything is well insulated and mechnically robust, not the current flow.